# Show the highest price of a grouped product in catalog

Tags: catalog, price, grouped-products

In the online store I'm making, I only have grouped products. And which one of them have 3 single products.
One has a fixed price, and the other two, variable prices, that start from 0. And the problem is just that.

As the products start at 0, it doesn't appear any price in the catalog. 
So what I wanted was to show the highest price, that it'll be the product with the fixed price.

I tried this at: 
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/price.php`

changed this function:

```
/ ** 
      * Apply group for product price 
      * 
      * @ Param $ product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product 
      * @ Param float $ finalPrice 
      * @ Return float 
      * / 

     protected function _applyGroupPrice ($ product, $ finalPrice) 

     {

         $ groupPrice = $ product-> getGroupPrice (); 

         if (is_numeric ($ groupPrice)) {

             finalPrice $ = **min** (finalPrice $, $ groupPrice); 

         } 

         return $ finalPrice; 

     }
```

to

```
/ ** 
      * Apply group for product price 
      * 
      * @ Param $ product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product 
      * @ Param float $ finalPrice 
      * @ Return float 
      * / 

     protected function _applyGroupPrice ($ product, $ finalPrice) 

     {

         $ groupPrice = $ product-> getGroupPrice (); 

         if (is_numeric ($ groupPrice)) {

             finalPrice $ = **max** (finalPrice $, $ groupPrice); 

         } 

         return $ finalPrice; 

     }
```

But no luck. Any other idea?

Thank you